# Override the values in the method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an online store. There is a column price(using the gem [money](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money)). And there is a column "discount". And if the store Manager records the price in column "discount", the store needs to display the price(column "discount") I Think that I need to override "price" in the model. but I don't know how to access the column "price"?

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  monetize :price_cents
  monetize :discount_cents


  def price
    if self.discount > 0
      self.discount
    else
      ?
      If I call, 
      self.price
      it turns out called once again this method.
      self[:price]
      = nil, why?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Try `read_attribute(:price)`.

Comment: if `read_attribute(:price) => nil`. If `price => #<Money fractional:50000 currency:RUB>`

Comment: From what I can see, it looks like you have a method price, not the column. Can you show the table definition from a migration or schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super` may work, or consider using [decorators](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) for this kind of stuff.